# Float values are being read without decimal places

Tags: python, excel, pandas, floating-point, precision

These are the values in the excel file:

- 7257.5679
- 6942.0949714286
- 5780.0125476250005

This is my read_excel:

```
DataFrame = pd.read_excel(File_Name, names=['id', 'value'], dtype={'id': str, 'value': float})
```

Pandas output:

- 7258
- 6942
- 5780

In the database:

- 7257.5679
- 6942.0949714286
- 5780.0125476250005

What I want in pandas AND in database (FLOAT column):

- 7258.56
- 6942.09
- 5780.01

How can I change the read_excel to achieve this result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your pandas display precision?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your file? What is the output of `DataFrame.info()`?

Comment: @BigBen Apparently that's right, but I'm sending this data to the database in a FLOAT column, and there the values are not being rounded, they are complete the same as in excel, only the dataframe is different!

Comment: Sounds like it's your display precision then, and nothing to do with `read_excel`.

Comment: @BigBen But the database is receiving the complete record, how can I modify the dataframe so that when inserting it into the database it only has two decimal places?

Comment: Lots of questions here on SO on how to truncate decimal places: https://www.google.com/search?q=truncate+decimal+places+pandas+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Code works fine for me with same data in .XLSX file. DF has 7257.567900 etc.

Comment: @user19077881 Apparently I was just confused by the fact that the dataframe didn't show the decimal places but the database inserted them with decimal places, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The example in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:%7E:text=squeeze%20the%20data.-,dtypeType,-name%20or%20dict) uses numpy types:

`{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}`.

Have you tried using `np.float64`?

Comment: The output was the same, and the record shown in the dataframe is not inserted in the database, but what was in excel!

Comment: Apparently I was just confused by the fact that the dataframe didn't show the decimal places but the database inserted them with decimal places, thanks anyway!